# Postgres Hung Transaction

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jdbc

We have a Java application that connects to a Postgres database. Occasionally the Java application runs out of memory and dies because it was waiting on a response to a transaction sent to the database that was never returned.

I enabled logging of pg_locks and transactions on a 1 minute interval for the time period the problem has been occurring. I found the transaction that is causing the problem, but it appears to be hung.

It's doing a simple update statement on a table with no more than 10 records, but it sits there in transaction for hours. There is nothing in the pg_locks view to indicate this transaction is waiting on a lock, but I don't know why it gets hung up. As soon as we kill the Java application and restart it, that transaction clears out and business continues as normal. The question is, what can cause this transaction to get hung?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/910CF843580B3C40A25CD0D04B3908E21306BB@exchange4.comune.prato.local

Comment: are you doing connection pooling?  Please add  more information to your question.(such as postgres version, driver version etc.)

Comment: I'll have to ask the developers on the connection pooling question. Unfortunately this is an older application, it seems the JDBC jar file doesn't have the version listed in it's filename and it's not listed in the jar manifest either so I don't know how else to determine which version it is. We are using postgres 9.2. Also, this is a lightly used database, during the problem time there aren't really any other transactions happening (except for a delete statement on the same table that started at the same time and appears to be waiting on the first transaction to finish)

Comment: You can run `java -cp yourjar.jar org.postgresql.util.PSQLDriverVersion` to get the driver's version (replace `yourjar.jar` with the actual filename)

Comment: thanks for that command, looks like PostgreSQL 9.1 JDBC4 <build 903>